# input field validation with keycode functions not working as expected in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keycode, capslock

I'm using a QWERTZ-keyboard and want to write a validation script for a text input field. Unfortunately no matter what I try following chars still show in Chrome: ^ and ´ even if I just allow some keys and use `e.preventDefault()` for the others.

I also tried not to allow capslock with this statement

```
if(e.originalEvent.getModifierState("CapsLock")==true)
```

but in the Chrome console with active capsLock it always returns false.

In Firefox everything works just fine. What is the reason for this and how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$('#yourInputText').keypress(function(e) { // or catch any other event you want
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
        alert('caps is on');
    }
});
```

Comment: thx, but that would only work for letters, not for numbers and special chars.